# Rollback Kernel Ubuntu 14.04.2

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel, ubuntu-14.04, downgrade

I have looked at many answers on here but no matter what it doesn't seem to work.

Fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04.2, trying to install an older kernel. I only have SSH access no GUI etc.

What i have done so far:

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-image-3.13.0-46-generic_3.13.0-46.79_amd64.deb
dpkg -i linux-image-3.13.0-46-generic_3.13.0-46.79_amd64.deb
grep "menuentry" /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

I have 4 in total:

1. 3.13.0-52
2. 3.13.0-52 recovery
3. 3.13.0-46
4. 3.13.0.46 recovery

I ran:

```
nano /etc/default/grub
```

Here i have tried a bunch of different things suggested

```
GRUB_DEFAULT="2>0"
GRUB_DEFAULT="saved"
GRUB_DEFAULT=2
GRUB_DEFAULT="Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-46-generic>Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-52-generic
```

Then running:

```
sudo update-grub
reboot
```

Every time it boots straight back into -52-generic.

Reason: Some app i use is awaiting a kernel update (54 hopefully) to fix it but for now 46 is recommended.

Comment: So you have installed the kernel, but you can't boot it?  Edit `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` and put `set default=2` just before the first menu entry.  You may as well put in `set timeout=10` as well.  This isn't the "right" way to do it, but if it boots, then we can fix `default/grub`

Comment: @Paul 52 still. `uname -r 3.13.0-52-generic`

Comment: Interesting - did the grub menu appear?  If not, hold down shift at boot time.

Comment: @Paul Sorry i am remote with SSH

Comment: Wow, this is risky for remote work, given the kernel is untested.  Could you put the entire grub.cfg on pastebin so we can see what it is doing?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/esYGaetw i have reset it, originally i had it set default 2 on line 19.

Comment: Ok, if you are confident, you can copy and paste the entire menuentry for .46 to before the first .52.  It will then be at default 0 and will be the one run next.  If the kernel fails though, you'll need a remote KVM or go on-site.

Comment: (don't run update-grub after manual changes to grub.cfg)